# DropDownMultiSelect in overlay not showing correctly

Tags: flutter

I have created DropDownMultiSelect in an overlay, but when I press the arrow to select from my options, the menu appears under the overlay for some reason.

Code of the DropDownMultiSelect in overlayEntry:

```
List<String> categories = ['General', 'Sports', 'Science'];
List<String> selectedCategories = [];

overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) {
      return Material(
      child:DropDownMultiSelect(
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: height * 0.05,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 175, 1),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (List<String> value) {
                        selectedCategories = value;
                        overlayEntry!.markNeedsBuild();
                      },
                      options: categories,
                      selectedValues: selectedCategories,
                      whenEmpty: 'Select Categories',
                      selected_values_style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: height * 0.05,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 175, 1),
                      ),
                    ),
      )
```